# How to use android keystore provider api in 4.3 to store app private keys

Tags: android

I want to store some secure data like say login password of my application after some searching I found that the keystore provider apis added in android version 4.3 can be used for this. I also went through the demo example for Keystore provider in sdk samples but I am not getting how to use the keystore provider to save my application secrets. Can anyone please explain how exactly can i use keystore provider apis to store my login password.

Also I went through keychain and had a similar queries. Can keychain apis also be used for storing my login password? If yes how do I proceed with it.

Any Link or good tutorial will help for clarifying my concepts.

Thanks,
Sagar

Comment: Did you get an answer to this?